# Изображение в карточке товара Opencart

Tags: opencart

http://vps25273nl.hyperhost.name/ 
Вот сам сайт. Редактирую шаблон. Допустим загружаю картинку в товар, она квадратная, код изменяет ее в прямоугольную. Подскажите как мне оставить ее квадратной?
Вот может понадобится код файл image в system/library

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package     OpenCart
 * @author      Daniel Kerr
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2005 - 2017, OpenCart, Ltd. (https://www.opencart.com/)
 * @license     https://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0
 * @link        https://www.opencart.com
*/

/**
* Image class
*/
class Image {
    private $file;
    private $image;
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $bits;
    private $mime;
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param   string  $file
 *
*/
public function __construct($file) {
    if (!extension_loaded('gd')) {
        exit('Error: PHP GD is not installed!');
    }

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $this->file = $file;

        $info = getimagesize($file);

        $this->width  = $info[0];
        $this->height = $info[1];
        $this->bits = isset($info['bits']) ? $info['bits'] : '';
        $this->mime = isset($info['mime']) ? $info['mime'] : '';

        if ($this->mime == 'image/gif') {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        } elseif ($this->mime == 'image/png') {
            $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        } elseif ($this->mime == 'image/jpeg') {
            $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        }
    } else {
        exit('Error: Could not load image ' . $file . '!');
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @return  string
 */
public function getFile() {
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @return  array
 */
public function getImage() {
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @return  string
 */
public function getWidth() {
    return $this->width;
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @return  string
 */
public function getHeight() {
    return $this->height;
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @return  string
 */
public function getBits() {
    return $this->bits;
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @return  string
 */
public function getMime() {
    return $this->mime;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   string  $file
 * @param   int     $quality
 */
public function save($file, $quality = 90) {
    $info = pathinfo($file);

    $extension = strtolower($info['extension']);

    if (is_resource($this->image)) {
        if ($extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'jpg') {
            imagejpeg($this->image, $file, $quality);
        } elseif ($extension == 'png') {
            imagepng($this->image, $file);
        } elseif ($extension == 'gif') {
            imagegif($this->image, $file);
        }

        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   int $width
 * @param   int $height
 * @param   string  $default
 */
public function resize($width = 0, $height = 0, $default = '') {
    if (!$this->width || !$this->height) {
        return;
    }

    $xpos = 0;
    $ypos = 0;
    $scale = 1;

    $scale_w = $width / $this->width;
    $scale_h = $height / $this->height;

    if ($default == 'w') {
        $scale = $scale_w;
    } elseif ($default == 'h') {
        $scale = $scale_h;
    } else {
        $scale = min($scale_w, $scale_h);
    }

    if ($scale == 1 && $scale_h == $scale_w && $this->mime != 'image/png') {
        return;
    }

    $new_width = (int)($this->width * $scale);
    $new_height = (int)($this->height * $scale);
    $xpos = (int)(($width - $new_width) / 2);
    $ypos = (int)(($height - $new_height) / 2);

    $image_old = $this->image;
    $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    if ($this->mime == 'image/png') {
        imagealphablending($this->image, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
        $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
    } else {
        $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);

    imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->width, $this->height);
    imagedestroy($image_old);

    $this->width = $width;
    $this->height = $height;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   string  $watermark
 * @param   string  $position
 */
public function watermark($watermark, $position = 'bottomright') {
    switch($position) {
        case 'topleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
        case 'topcenter':
            $watermark_pos_x = intval(($this->width - $watermark->getWidth()) / 2);
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
        case 'topright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->width - $watermark->getWidth();
            $watermark_pos_y = 0;
            break;
        case 'middleleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = intval(($this->height - $watermark->getHeight()) / 2);
            break;
        case 'middlecenter':
            $watermark_pos_x = intval(($this->width - $watermark->getWidth()) / 2);
            $watermark_pos_y = intval(($this->height - $watermark->getHeight()) / 2);
            break;
        case 'middleright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->width - $watermark->getWidth();
            $watermark_pos_y = intval(($this->height - $watermark->getHeight()) / 2);
            break;
        case 'bottomleft':
            $watermark_pos_x = 0;
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->height - $watermark->getHeight();
            break;
        case 'bottomcenter':
            $watermark_pos_x = intval(($this->width - $watermark->getWidth()) / 2);
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->height - $watermark->getHeight();
            break;
        case 'bottomright':
            $watermark_pos_x = $this->width - $watermark->getWidth();
            $watermark_pos_y = $this->height - $watermark->getHeight();
            break;
    }

    imagealphablending( $this->image, true );
    imagesavealpha( $this->image, true );
    imagecopy($this->image, $watermark->getImage(), $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0, $watermark->getWidth(), $watermark->getHeight());

    imagedestroy($watermark->getImage());
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   int     $top_x
 * @param   int     $top_y
 * @param   int     $bottom_x
 * @param   int     $bottom_y
 */
public function crop($top_x, $top_y, $bottom_x, $bottom_y) {
    $image_old = $this->image;
    $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($bottom_x - $top_x, $bottom_y - $top_y);

    imagecopy($this->image, $image_old, 0, 0, $top_x, $top_y, $this->width, $this->height);
    imagedestroy($image_old);

    $this->width = $bottom_x - $top_x;
    $this->height = $bottom_y - $top_y;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   int     $degree
 * @param   string  $color
 */
public function rotate($degree, $color = 'FFFFFF') {
    $rgb = $this->html2rgb($color);

    $this->image = imagerotate($this->image, $degree, imagecolorallocate($this->image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]));

    $this->width = imagesx($this->image);
    $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
}

/**
 * 
 *
 */
private function filter() {
    $args = func_get_args();

    call_user_func_array('imagefilter', $args);
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   string  $text
 * @param   int     $x
 * @param   int     $y 
 * @param   int     $size
 * @param   string  $color
 */
private function text($text, $x = 0, $y = 0, $size = 5, $color = '000000') {
    $rgb = $this->html2rgb($color);

    imagestring($this->image, $size, $x, $y, $text, imagecolorallocate($this->image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]));
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   object  $merge
 * @param   object  $x
 * @param   object  $y
 * @param   object  $opacity
 */
private function merge($merge, $x = 0, $y = 0, $opacity = 100) {
    imagecopymerge($this->image, $merge->getImage(), $x, $y, 0, 0, $merge->getWidth(), $merge->getHeight(), $opacity);
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param   string  $color
 * 
 * @return  array
 */
private function html2rgb($color) {
    if ($color[0] == '#') {
        $color = substr($color, 1);
    }

    if (strlen($color) == 6) {
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[1], $color[2] . $color[3], $color[4] . $color[5]);
    } elseif (strlen($color) == 3) {
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[0], $color[1] . $color[1], $color[2] . $color[2]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $r = hexdec($r);
    $g = hexdec($g);
    $b = hexdec($b);

    return array($r, $g, $b);
}
```

}

Comment: какая версия opencart?

Comment: версия opencart 3.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо менять настройки ресайза изображений в админке, лезть в класс Image по такому вопросу не рекоммендую.

> Opencart 3.x.x
>
> Админ > Расширения/Extensions > Расширения/Extensions > Темы/Themes > Редактировать

В секции **Image** данного раздела содержаться установки размеров изображений для всего сайта в px.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я думал придется долго искать в коде!